# RecursiveIteratorIterator returns extra elements

Tags: php, iterator

`RecursiveIteratorIterator` returns extra result if `rewind()` is not called before `while` loop

Example

```
$array = array("A","B","C");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
//$iterator->rewind() ; this would fix it 
while ( $iterator->valid() ) {
    print($iterator->current()) ;
    $iterator->next();
}
```

Output

```
AABC  <--- Instead of ABC
```

- Why an extra `A` not  `C` ?
- The Array has never been initiated or called why is `$iterator->rewind()` required for while loop
- `foreach` works perfectly without having to call `rewind` whats the differences between `foreach` and `while` when working with iterators

[Code In action](http://3v4l.org/O6Z6u)

Comment: IteratorIterator also behaves weird if you don't call rewind. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458955/why-must-i-rewind-iteratoriterator

Comment: @rambocoder just observed that too ..  this is looking more like a bug

Comment: I left it alone because while my first intuition if I were writing spl, would be to have coded it [like this](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/iteratoriterator_8inc_source.html) (just forwarding the method calls), with maybe a bool variable to cache the return values. But, when I started to think about stuff like `CachingIterator` and would the whole Iterator/Decorator paradigm still work with complex iterators like `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, and would exceptions/errors be thrown at insane moments, it was too complicated to think about without a lot of effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to answer the questions in reverse order:

> `foreach` works perfectly without having to call `rewind` whats the differences between those `foreach` and `while` when working with iterators

`foreach` internally does a call to `rewind()`, that's why you don't have to do it yourself. This is always done, so even if you have already used an iterator, the `foreach` loop will start over from the beginning. (You can avoid this by wrapping it in a `NoRewindIterator`).

> The Array has never been initiated or called why is $iterator->rewind() required for while loop

The SPL iterators are designed to be used with `foreach` and to avoid duplicate method calls in this case. If the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` would call the `RecursiveArrayIterator::rewind()` method on construction, then it would be called again when the `foreach` loop starts. That's why the call isn't done.

> Why an extra A not C ?

To figure this out it is nice to see which methods of the `RecursiveArrayIterator` actually get called:

```
<?php

class DebugRAI extends RecursiveArrayIterator {
    public function rewind() { echo __METHOD__, "\n"; return parent::rewind(); }
    public function current() { echo __METHOD__, "\n"; return parent::current(); }
    public function key() { echo __METHOD__, "\n"; return parent::key(); }
    public function valid() { echo __METHOD__, "\n"; return parent::valid(); }
    public function next() { echo __METHOD__, "\n"; return parent::next(); }
}

$array = array("A", "B", "C");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new DebugRAI($array));
while ($iterator->valid()) {
    echo $iterator->current(), "\n";
    $iterator->next();
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
DebugRAI::valid
DebugRAI::current
A
DebugRAI::valid
DebugRAI::valid
A
DebugRAI::next
DebugRAI::valid
DebugRAI::valid
DebugRAI::current
B
DebugRAI::next
DebugRAI::valid
DebugRAI::valid
DebugRAI::current
C
DebugRAI::next
DebugRAI::valid
DebugRAI::valid
```

The output looks a bit odd, in particular the second iteration misses the `next()` call, so it just stays at the same element.

The reason for this is a peculiarity in the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` implementation: Iterators start off in the `RS_START` state and the first `next` call in this state only checks `hasChildren()`, but does not actually call the underlying iterator's `next()` method. After this was done it switches into the `RS_NEXT` mode in which the `next()` call happens properly. That's why the forward move is delayed by one step.

In my eyes this is a bug, but https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44063 claims otherwise.

Comment: It looks like a PHP bug. If you have very important reason to know it and nobody here is able to answer try you luck in ext/spl/spl_iterators.c

Comment: It's also with some other iterators that calling `valid()` gives unexpected results unless the iterator is not properly initialized that is both with having `__contruct()` called as well as having `rewind()` called before `valid()` can be called. If you can not work around that, you can wrap with [`CachingIterator`](http://php.net/CachingIterator).